# How do I close background jobs when I quit iTerm2?

Tags: shell, iterm

OS X's Terminal application closes background jobs when you quit the application. How do I achieve this behavior in iTerm2?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This short screen share](http://youtu.be/pRua1Iwnjag) demonstrates that iTerm2 *does* kill background processes when closing tabs that spawned background processes.  What process is getting left around for you?

Comment: I'm seeing something similar; processes running (not necessarily in the background) when iTerm is quit appear to still be running in Activity Monitor. Try for example running ``yes`` then quitting iTerm.